# Unable to insert document into shard collections

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongo-shell

I am getting error "Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr"
While inserting document into any of the shard collections.

My setup is like

> rs0: mongon1, mongon2, mongon3
>
> rs1: mongon4, mongon5, mongon6 On port 27017
>
> Config: mongoconf1, mongoconf2, mongoconf3 all on port 27019
>
> Mongos on mongom: 27017
> Successfully started mongos using following command on mongos server

```
mongos --configdb configReplSet/mongoconfs1:27019,mongoconfs2:27019,mongoconfs3:27019
```

Following is my shard status

```
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5b21a5847e4ba64674ee085e")
  }
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/mongon1:27017,mongon2:27017,mongon3:27017",  "state" : 1 }
    {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/mongodbn5:27017,mongon4:27017,mongon6:27017",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
    "3.6.5" : 1
  autosplit:
    Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  5
    Last reported error:  Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set rs0
    Time of Reported error:  Thu Jun 14 2018 00:44:12 GMT+0000 (UTC)
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
            No recent migrations
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
            config.system.sessions
                    shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                    unique: false
                    balancing: true
                    chunks:
                            rs1     1
                    { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs1 Timestamp(1, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "experimentine",  "primary" : "rs1",  "partitioned" : true }
    {  "_id" : "experimentone",  "primary" : "rs1",  "partitioned" : true }
            experimentone.run1
                    shard key: { "id" : 1 }
                    unique: false
                    balancing: true
                    chunks:
                            rs1     1
                    { "id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs1 Timestamp(1, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "masterdb",  "primary" : "rs0",  "partitioned" : true }
            masterdb.mastercollection
                    shard key: { "id" : 1 }
                    unique: false
                    balancing: true
                    chunks:
                            rs0     1
                    { "id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "test",  "primary" : "rs0",  "partitioned" : false }
    {  "_id" : "testdb",  "primary" : "rs0",  "partitioned" : true }
            testdb.demo
                    shard key: { "name" : 1 }
                    unique: false
                    balancing: true
                    chunks:
                            rs0     1
                    { "name" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "name" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs0 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

**Please help me identifying where I am going wrong.**

Answer (score 0):

I identified the issue with inserts. I was using **mongodb.conf** files and in those config file I must mention sharding: details, of the node is part of shard cluster. I missed to enter sharding details in the mongod.conf file of all the mongod servers which are part of shard set.

All my mongod nodes should have following in ** sharding** section of mongod.conf file.

```
#sharding:
sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr
```